# How do I generate formatted permalinks as specified in backend options?

Tags: php, posts, permalinks, urls

I searched everywhere for this but couldn't find any help. I'm working on a plugin that generates posts from a database, like so:

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $content = $core->parseTpl($item->Asin, $this->content);
    $titleColumn = $this->titleColumn;
    $postarr     = array(
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_title'   => $item->$titleColumn,
        'post_status'  => 'draft',
    );

    $postId = wp_insert_post( $postarr );

    //more code...
}
```

When I do this, the generated permalinks look something like this:

http://mywebsite/?p=1190

However, I want the permalinks to look like specified in the WP-backend:

[image]

Using the wp_insert_post function doesn't seem to apply the permalink formatting. What do I have to do, so that my created posts have the formatted permalinks?

Comment: The real generated URL format for every post is `/?p=123`, the pretty permalink is being generated later using rewrite rules. What does it output if you use `get_permalink($id);`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make draft posts or posts in review accessible via full url / slug?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218168/how-to-make-draft-posts-or-posts-in-review-accessible-via-full-url-slug)

Comment: When I use `get_permalink($id)` I get `/?p=123`